# Jquery on android not working

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, offline

I am building a website in html for an offline use (very important). The use is to show the client catalogue

So the client wants to have a sideshow on a few page to show the how some product flow will the he explain it . so it needs to be a manual slider.

I have build it it work on my computer. However when I put it on my phone a Galaxy note 3. The Jquery dose not load and I have all the image on top of each other.

I tried different slider including revolution slider.

```
 <head>
 <script class="rs-file" src="assets/royalslider/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
 <script class="rs-file" src="assets/royalslider/jquery.royalslider.min.js"></script>
 <link class="rs-file" href="assets/royalslider/royalslider.css" rel="stylesheet">
 <!-- syntax highlighter -->
 <script src="assets/preview-assets/js/highlight.pack.js"></script>
 <script src="assets/preview-assets/js/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"></script>
   <!-- syntax highlighter -->
  <script src="assets/preview-assets/js/highlight.pack.js"></script>
   <script src="assets/preview-assets/js/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js"></script>
 </head>
 <body>
   <div class="sliderContainer fullWidth clearfix">
      <div id="full-width-slider" class="royalSlider heroSlider rsMinW">
       <div class="rsContent">
   <img class="rsImg" src="img/full-width/1.jpg" alt="" />
   <div class="infoBlock infoBlockLeftBlack rsABlock" data-fade-effect="" data-move-offset="10" data-move-effect="bottom" data-speed="200">
   <h4>This is an animated block, add any number of them to any type of slide</h4>
  <p>Put completely anything inside - text, images, inputs, links, buttons.</p>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="rsContent">
  <img class="rsImg" src="img/full-width/2.jpg" alt="" />
 <div class="infoBlock  rsAbsoluteEl" style="color:#000;" data-fade-effect="" data-move-offset="10" data-move-effect="bottom" data-speed="200">
  <h4>This is a static HTML block</h4>
  <p>It's always displayed and not animated by slider.</p>
 </div>
 </div>
  <div class="rsContent">
   <img class="rsImg" src="img/full-width/3.jpg" alt="" />
   <div class="infoBlock rsABlock infoBlockLeftBlack" data-fade-effect="" data-move-offset="10" data-move-effect="bottom" data-speed="200">
  <h4>You can link to this slide by adding #3 to url.</h4>
  <p><a href="http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/gallery-with-deeplinking/">Learn more</a></p>
  </div>
   </div>
  <div class="rsContent">
   <img class="rsImg" src="img/full-width/4.jpg" alt="" />
   <span class="photosBy rsAbsoluteEl" data-fade-effect="fa;se" data-move-offset="40" data-move-effect="bottom" data-speed="200">Photos by <a href="http://www.flickr.com/photos/gilderic/">Gilderic</a></span>
    </div>
 </div>
 </div>



 <script id="addJS">jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('#full-width-slider').royalSlider({
arrowsNav: true,
loop: false,
keyboardNavEnabled: true,
controlsInside: false,
imageScaleMode: 'fill',
arrowsNavAutoHide: false,
autoScaleSlider: true, 
autoScaleSliderWidth: 960,     
autoScaleSliderHeight: 350,
controlNavigation: 'bullets',
thumbsFitInViewport: false,
navigateByClick: true,
startSlideId: 0,
autoPlay: false,
transitionType:'move',
globalCaption: false,
deeplinking: {
  enabled: true,
  change: false
},
 /* size of all images http://help.dimsemenov.com/kb/royalslider-jquery-plugin-faq/adding-width-and-height-properties-to-images */
imgWidth: 1400,
imgHeight: 680
   });
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: @Mighter Here is the code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to test some plugins on your device, before You start doing Your project.

here is some plugins for presentation.
[bespoke.js](http://markdalgleish.com/projects/bespoke.js/)

[reveal.js](http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/1)

And [here](http://jquery-plugins.net/search?q=slideshow) try to find some alternatives.

Comment: But the JS file do not load